# RecyclerView onItemTouchListener conflicts when onScroll and onLongPress case

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, long-press

Here is my problem, I have a RecyclerView which I must handle both long press and scroll and move events. Basically I want to intercept the long press when user scrolls. And when the long press occured I want to intercept scrolling but continue to do some actions on ACTION_MOVE after long pressed. This is what I have so far

```
recyclerView.setOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent ev) {

            final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // Release the scroll.
                mIsScrolling = false;
                gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(ev);
                return false;
            }

            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            // when user scrolls it comes here
            return true; // to handle scroll on onTouchEvent
            }
        }

        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallow) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
             //never comes here after return true onInterceptTouchEvent
        }

    });
```

initializing gestureDetectorCompat

```
gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(context,getOnGestureListener());

public GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener getOnGestureListener() {

    return new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
             if(!mIsScrolling)
             //do something
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            mIsScrolling = true;
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

this topics I checked so far but didn't help in my case with recycler view

[Move Events AFTER LongPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651082/move-events-after-longpress)

[Android long press with scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093232/android-long-press-with-scroll)

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: do you have found solution ?

Comment: Yes. onInterceptTouchEvent method, decide what action type you should intercept (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE in my case) end return true for that case. Then handle it in onTouchEvent method